# How can I install a specific core version?

Tags: 8, updating, composer

Composer always installs the latest version of Drupal core, but I want Drupal 8.6, not Drupal 8.7.

How can I install a specific core version?

Comment: Did you specify an exact version?

Comment: If you mean like this: composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.6.17 some-dir --no-interaction this will give an error "Could not find package drupal-composer/drupal-project with version 8.6.17. ", I also change the versions in composer.json e.g. use --no-install and then edit composer.json and run the install - still 8.7.4 at this time. I assume I must be missing something.

Comment: Drupal-project is not the same as core Drupal

Answer (score 8):

Now Drupal recommended project supports version as command line option. If you want to install version 8.8.5 via Composer then command will like as shown below.

`composer create-project drupal/recommended-project:8.8.5 <INSTALL_DIR>`

Answer (score 6):

Create drupal-project with --no-install option:

```
composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev my_site_name_dir --no-interaction --no-install
```

Change directories to my_site_name_dir and edit the version contraints in the composer.json file:

```
"require": {
    ...
    "drupal/core": "8.6.*",
    ...
},
```

Also for

```
"require-dev": {
    "webflo/drupal-core-require-dev": "8.6.*"
},
```

> webflo/drupal-core-require-dev provides the require-dev dependencies
> of drupal/core as a standalone package. It follows the same release
> cycle and versioning scheme as Drupal core. You should use the same
> version constraint for it as you use for Drupal core.

Run `composer install`

---

#### Warning

Since answering the question the de-facto standard for installing Drupal via composer has changed from drupal-composer/drupal-project to drupal/recommended-project. Now you can append the version directly to the package. See [Vinod Singh's answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/294656).

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes I just figured this out in a round about way - what you've posted here is what I really wanted. Cheers!

Comment: This is great, and it's helping me to follow the guide at https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/install/add-composer-to-an-existing-site ... thanks @4x4!

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was not setting the correct webflo/drupal-core-require-dev version along it the drupal/core version, so composer.json should look like this:

```
{
    "name": "drupal-composer/drupal-project",
    "description": "Project template for Drupal 8 projects with composer",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "role": ""
        }
    ],
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6",
        "composer/installers": "^1.2",
        "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.6.5",
        "drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold": "^2.5",
        "drupal/console": "^1.0.2",
        "drupal/core": "8.6.17",
        "drush/drush": "^9.0.0",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4",
        "webflo/drupal-finder": "^1.0.0",
        "webmozart/path-util": "^2.3",
        "zaporylie/composer-drupal-optimizations": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "webflo/drupal-core-require-dev": "8.6.17"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "scripts/composer/ScriptHandler.php"
        ],
        "files": ["load.environment.php"]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "pre-install-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true,
        "patchLevel": {
            "drupal/core": "-p2"
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "web/core": ["type:drupal-core"],
            "web/libraries/{$name}": ["type:drupal-library"],
            "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
            "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
            "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
            "drush/Commands/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"]
        },
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "initial": {
                ".editorconfig": "../.editorconfig",
                ".gitattributes": "../.gitattributes"
            }
        }
    }
}
```